# How to delete file from Google cloud platfrom shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to remove the file from `cd /var  cd www/html` folder using the command:

`rm phpinfo.php.save` but it is saying, permission denied.

Below I am attaching the screenshot.

[image]

**Edit: 1** Tried below command, still not worked

```
ersaurabh101@gcp-test:/var/www/html$ gsutil -m rm gs://www/html/phpinfo.php.save
CommandException: 1 files/objects could not be removed.
```

Comment: I didn't really work with Google Cloud but doesn't something like `sudo rm -f phpinfo.php.save` work?

Comment: worked :) .. thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Remember whenever there's a permission denied `sudo` is your best friend.

Comment: noted.. thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo rm -f phpinfo.php.save` command instead. Whenever there is a permission denied `sudo` is your best friend. The `sudo` allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or another user, as specified by the security policy.

Answer (score 0):

Online command bash is

```
gcloud beta compute --project "ID_PROJECT" ssh USER@INSTANCE --command="cd /var/www/html && rm phpinfo.php" --zone "us-central1-a"
```

or full permission with user root

```
gcloud beta compute --project "ID_PROJECT" ssh root@INSTANCE --command="cd /var/www/html && rm phpinfo.php" --zone "us-central1-a"
```

[gcloud compute ssh](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh)